# Using \dontrun{} with @example in R

Tags: r, roxygen2

In writing the documentation of my package, I include the examples in the .Rd files by calling the example codes from another folder, i.e., as follows:

```r
#' @example ./inst/eg/example.R
```

However, I do not want to run them when I'm checking the code in `devtools::check()`. May I know how to do this with the `\dontrun{}` command?

I tried something like the following, but it does not work.

```r
#' @example \dontrun{./inst/eg/example.R}
```

Thank you!

Comment: This was discussed in [this github issue](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/issues/1010) but it seems they decided not to implement that.